# cuda Assertion failed when not compiling the model

Tags: pytorch

we have an error from within Cuda that says
`` Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed ``

we couldnt find the reason for that. Only when used torch.compile on the model, it eliminated the failure.

```
             self.model = torch.compile(self.model).to(self.device)
```

any ideas why this could have solved the assertion failure? we would like to understand the original failure

thanks for any ideas
Lior